# The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Product>'

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-getx

**This is my controller class as I am using GetX controller with null safety**

```
    // ignore_for_file: file_names
    import 'package:get/state_manager.dart';
    import 'package:today/models/product.dart';

    import 'package:today/services/api.dart';

    class ProductController extends GetxController {
      var isLoading = true.obs;
      var productList = <Product>[].obs;

      @override
      void onInit() {
        fetchProducts();
        super.onInit();
      }

      void fetchProducts() async {
        try {
          isLoading(true);
          var products = await RemoteServices.fetchProducts();
          if (products != null) {
            productList.value = products;
          }
        } finally {
          isLoading(false);
        }
      }
    }
```

**This is my model clas created using quicktype.io**

```
    // To parse this JSON data, do
    //
    //     final product = productFromJson(jsonString);

    import 'dart:convert';

    List<Product> productFromJson(String str) =>
        List<Product>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Product.fromJson(x)));

    String productToJson(List<Product> data) =>
        json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

    class Product {
      Product({
        required this.id,
        required this.name,
        required this.details,
        required this.price,
        required this.color,
        required this.stock,
        required this.image,
      });

      int id;
      String name;
      String details;
      double price;
      String color;
      int stock;
      String image;

      factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Product(
            id: json["id"],
            name: json["name"],
            details: json["details"],
            price: json["price"].toDouble(),
            color: json["color"],
            stock: json["stock"],
         image: json["image"],
      );

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "id": id,
            "name": name,
            "details": details,
            "price": price,
            "color": color,
            "stock": stock,
            "image": image,
          };
    }
```

**I don't know how to solve this issue, please help me!**
**edit: this is my remoteservices class**

```
    // ignore: avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter

// ignore_for_file: avoid_print

    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:today/models/product.dart';

    class RemoteServices {
      static var client = http.Client();

      static Future<List?> fetchProducts() async {
        try {
          String link = 
    "https://devswagger.aquaticxpressshipping.com/api/Products";
          var url = Uri.parse(link);
          var response = await http.get(
            url,
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "Authorization":
                  "Bearer 
`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IjMyZTJmYTZmLTdlNTEtNGQ4ZC1iNTQ3LTA3YzE5ZGRmYWZiOCIsInJvbGUiOiJVc2VyIiwibmJmIjoxNjMyMTA5NzQ0LCJleHAiOjE2MzI3MTQ1NDQsImlhdCI6MTYzMjEwOTc0NH0.cTROYSpeQHY5wavW-SPbyuHODTzT3wN7oDapy73pkMk",
            },
          );

          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            var jsonString = response.body;
            return productFromJson(jsonString);
          } else {
            //show error message
            return null;
          }
        } on Error catch (e) {
          print('General Error: $e');
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code of `RemoteServices.fetchProducts();` ?

Comment: @esentis, I am going to edit my question

Comment: Change the return type of `fetchProducts()` to `Future<List<Product>>`

Comment: Can you add the exact location where your error comes from? The debug console should give you the exact line for the error

Answer (score 0):

in the function named `productFromJson`
assign it to

```
 List<Product> productFromJson(String str) =>
        List<Product>.from(json.decode(str).map<Product>((x) => Product.fromJson(x)).toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the List as 'late' instead of null, and it will work fine